# How to set up correctly Google Tag Manager and Universal Analytics?

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, google-analytics

I have used Google Analytics but I am new to Google Tag Manager. I have installed the GTM extension by Slirx from Magento connect. It seems to support transactions and remarketing which as I understand are necessary functions.

Could you please explain: If one sets in Google Analytics tag type to **Transaction** instead of **Page View**, does that mean that page views will not be tracked but only transactions?

What should one do in order to have complete visitor tracking + the ecommerce data too?

Could you please explain shortly the whole process for Magento, clarifying all that, including the settings for Universal Analytics etc?

I am trying to set up correct visitor analytics for a new website.

Comment: I'm struggling, how does this relate to Magento? There are many great resources for GTM you can find all over the web.

Comment: I have explained how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page views will be used to track your individual visits to a page. For transactions you are moving to ecommerce tracking. The transaction would really only go on your order successful page once the customer has paid

For good resources to help you google has a great video analytics course to explain these concepts.

https://analyticsacademy.withgoogle.com/course05

Once equipped you will be able to set it up pretty easily.